# React - prevent re-rendering component if redux state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have some list in my application - there are screens like

```
ListScreen
CreateItemScreen
EditItemScreen
```

So firstly user goes to `ListScreen`, he can click "add item" and goes to `CreateItemScreen`. If he wants to delete item he needs to go to `EditItemScreen` and there is placed "Delete" button.

Items are stored in redux state - so when user creates item it's gonna be stored in redux. If user edits it - it's gonna be edited in redux. If he wants to delete item it needs to be deleted in redux.

When user click "Delete" system deletes it and redirect user back to `ListScreen`. Button system triggers delete item redux action, item is deleted and component is re-rendering - because redux state was changes so component's gonna be re-rendered. After it redirect is triggered(`react-router-dom`). But before redirect is triggered error appear. Because item is already deleted and screen is trying to take some item props.

Component looks like:

```
export const EditItemScreen = ({}) => {
  const { itemId } = useRouteMatch().params;
  const item = useSelector(getItemSelector(itemId));
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleDeleteClick = () => {
    history.replace('listPath');
    dispatch(deleteItem(itemId));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{item.title}</h1>

      <form>...form</form>

      <div>
        <button onClick={handleDeleteClick}>
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When user click "Delete" there is error which tells me that can't get `title` from undefined(because item is already deleted).

Can I prevent this last re-rendering? Just execute redirect before delete item and don't go back  to this screen and don't re-render it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do the dispatch before returning to the previous screen?

```
  dispatch(deleteItem(itemId));
  history.replace('listPath');
```

You want to leave the current component once everything is done so i think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try conditional rendering based on whether item.title is defined.